# JAVA JScrollPane not showing up

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel with scrollbar and i want to add a lot of JLabels to it. But the scrollbar doesnt work . I can not use the scrollbar and even after the panel is full it doesn't scroll . Here is my code  :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Scroll {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    p.add(scroll, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JButton but = new JButton("OK");
    p.add(but, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    but.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            panel.add(new JLabel("Some random text"));
            scroll.revalidate();
            p.repaint();p.revalidate();
        }
    });
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(800,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(p);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
}
```

Comment: Not the answer to your question but it seems you want to be using a `JList` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to lie with your layout managers. I think BorderLayout behaves strangely when you don't use the BorderLayout.CENTER position. I changed the line

```
p.add(scroll, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

to

```
p.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then, to make the text appear from the top instead of centering, I changed the layout manager for the panel component to a BoxLayout. From:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
```

to

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

This seems to have given me the functionality you want. Let me know if this fixes your issues or not!

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, you should probably use `JList` or `JTable` to implement your use case.

Regarding the issue, this is because all `BorderLayout` constraints except of `CENTER` will expand to as much space as their components occupy, even if that means that they will expand out of the screen bounds (in your case the `NORTH` section expands to the south after each button click).

To solve this, explicitly specify the preferred size for the components which can grow indefinitely if you add them to a non-central panel section with `BorderLayout`:

```
scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(-1, 100));
```

I use `-1` for the `width` here to indicate that it is not important (I could use any other value), since it will be ignored by the layout manager anyway (with `BorderLayout.NORTH` the component is stretched horizontally to take all the available horizontal space).